# Laravel Eloquent - Join 2 tables through other table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I build relationship between 2 tables through 3rd table. I have 3 tables in total.

**1.) addresses**

```
Schema::create('addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('line_1_number_building')->nullable();
    $table->text('line_2_number_street')->nullable();
    $table->text('line_3_area_locality')->nullable();
    $table->text('city')->nullable();
    $table->text('zip_code')->nullable();
    $table->text('state_province_county')->nullable();
    $table->text('country')->nullable();
    $table->longText('other_address_details')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**2.) staffs**

```
Schema::create('staffs', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('staff_category_id');
    $table->integer('gender_id');
    $table->text('staff_job_title')->nullable();
    $table->text('staff_first_name')->nullable();
    $table->text('staff_middle_name')->nullable();
    $table->text('staff_last_name')->nullable();
    $table->text('staff_qualifications')->nullable();
    $table->date('staff_birth_date');
    $table->longText('other_staff_details')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**3.) staff_addresses**

```
Schema::create('staff_addresses', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('staff_id');
    $table->integer('address_id');
    $table->date('date_address_from')->nullable();
    $table->date('date_address_to')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Now i want to get list of all addresses for any staff entry. I tried below code but it returns addresses which matches ID of Staff ID

What I tried

```
public function saddresses()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\addresses','App\staff_addresses','staff_id','id');
}
```

**What i got**

```
Address : [{"id":3,"line_1_number_building":"Hasan 2 line 1","line_2_number_street":"Hasan 2 line 2","line_3_area_locality":"Hasan 2 line 3","city":"Hasan 2 city","zip_code":"Hasan 2 zip code","state_province_county":"Hasan 2 state","country":"Hasan 2 country","other_address_details":"Hasan 2 other details","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"staff_id":5},{"id":4,"line_1_number_building":"Sadiq 2 line 1","line_2_number_street":"Sadiq 2 line 2","line_3_area_locality":"Sadiq 2 line 3","city":"Sadiq 2 city","zip_code":"Sadiq 2 zip code","state_province_county":"Sadiq 2 state","country":"Sadiq 2 country","other_address_details":"Sadiq 2 other details","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"staff_id":5}]
```

[Better view](https://jsonblob.com/06cce156-e23e-11e8-a8cb-5354c06498b4)

Can you please guide me how can i build proper relationship?

Regards,
Hasan Rajani.

Comment: show you controller function which have eloquent

Comment: From your tables it seems as though you may want the belongsToMany relationship.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is perfect @Capt. Teemo. But, if you want an address for particular one staff then here I have provided the solution.

You have to define this function in **Staff model**.

`public function addresses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\addresses');
}`

Query to get all addresses of $staffId (where $staffId is the id of staff table)

`$data = Staff::with('addresses')->where('id', $staffId)->first();`

And also if you want to get extra attributes in the pivot table, you must specify them when defining the relationship.

`public function addresses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\addresses')->withPivot('date_address_from', 'date_address_to');
}`

Also, you can maintain created_at and updated_at column automatically using `withTimestamps` method in the relationship.

For reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: Thank You Vandit P. Kotadiya for your help and guide :), However i got another quick solution for my problem on this website (https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)

created new function 'addresses' on Staff Model & then added pivot table name & joining fields name under as arguments ===> (return $this->belongsToMany('App\addresses','staff_addresses','staff_id','address_id');)

Answer (score 0):

First, try to fix your naming conventions. Things would be a lot easier if you follow laravel's naming convention. [Here is the guide](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions).

- **Pivot Tables** should be singular model names in alphabetical order (change `staff_addresses` to `address_staff`)

Then use `belongsToMany` relationship.

**staff** model:

```
public function addresses()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\addresses');
}
```

Here's how you query:

```
$data = Staff::with('addresses')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks Capt. Teemo for guiding me on naming conventions, This will help me a lot :). Actually I'm learning laravel and not sure many of functionalities and rules.

Comment: For my problem, i found this this solution helpful (https://laraveldaily.com/pivot-tables-and-many-to-many-relationships/)

created new function 'addresses' on Staff Model & then added pivot table name & joining fields name under as arguments ===> (return $this->belongsToMany('App\addresses','staff_addresses','staff_id','address_id');)

Comment: If you follow laravel naming conventions, you don't need to indicate the table name in your relation which is `staff_addresses`. Laravel automatically searches for `address_staff` as pivot since you are joining `addresses` and `staffs` table. Your argument would simply be `return $this->belongsToMany('App\addresses');`

Comment: Yes, I understand. I tried to change naming conventions and re-migrated but it messed up my entire setup, so i thought it's not a good idea to take this step at this stage. However it will help me in next project :). Currently learning laravel :) and i don't want to loose interest by redoing everything. Thanks for your help